# On the Definition of Large Deviation Principles

Tags: probability, large-deviation-theory

a Family of (real-valued) random variables $(X_\varepsilon)$ is said to satisfy a LDP with rate function $I$, if for any measurable set $A \in \mathcal{B}$ the following holds:
\begin{align}
    -\inf_{x \in A^{\circ}} I(x) \leq \liminf_{\varepsilon \to 0} \varepsilon \log P(X_\varepsilon \in A) 
    \leq \limsup_{\varepsilon \to 0} \varepsilon \log P(X_\varepsilon \in A)
    \leq -\inf_{x \in \overline{A}} I(x). \quad (1)
\end{align}
However, often times one finds statements of this sort:
\begin{align}
    I(x) = \lim \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} \varepsilon \log \mathbf{P}( X_\varepsilon \geq x) \quad (2)
\end{align}
where $x$ is greater than the mean of some limit $X_\varepsilon \to X$.
Now I understand that one obtains (1) from (2) with $A=(x,\infty)$ due to the semicontinuity of $I$. However it is not at all clear to my, how one would derive (1) from (2). Is that even true in general? If not, under what conditions is it true then?

Thanks in advance,

Leo

Comment: I deleted my previous answer as you have fixed the question!

Comment: (2) definitely implies the upper bound of (1). I'm not sure about the lower bound part, but it might help to look under what conditions (2) implies (1) for all *open balls* $A$

Comment: Theorem III.34 a) in the book "Large Deviations" by den Hollander gives a sketch on how to get from (2) to (1) for empirical averages. But the sketch might also be applicable in the more general setting.